# AzureAD with asp.net core - correlation failed when using http

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to implement user authentication with AzureAd in asp.net core 3.1 web app.

When the app runs on HTTPS protocol, it works ok. But when I try to run on non secure HTTP, it gives error

```
'.AspNetCore.Correlation.AzureADOpenID.4ts37wiZG7bAquJ4KQ6Z_eNtV8DGrkFyvZ6g63GEwq4' cookie not found.
---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
```

There is a minimum reproduce example:

Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using AzureAdTest.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace AzureAdTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services
                .AddAuthentication()
                .AddAzureAD(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                });

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme,
                options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Usage of authentication:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult AzureLogin(string returnUrl)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("AzureResponse", "Home", new {returnUrl});
    var properties =
        _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, redirectUrl);
    properties.AllowRefresh = true;
    properties.IsPersistent = true;
    return Challenge(properties, AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> AzureResponse(string returnUrl = "/")
{
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

    var email = info.Principal.Claims.First(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

    if (user != null)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, info.AuthenticationProperties);
        return RedirectToAction("Private");
    }
    else
    {
        return Forbid();
    }
}
```

I really need to make it work over http, because some of our developers can't use https for local debug.
What could be wrong here?

EDIT:
Both `http` and `https` endpoint are registered in Azure AD:

[image: registration URLs]

Comment: Can you please check and conform what is the redirect URL registered in your app registration?I believe url with `http` was not registered

Comment: I have registered both, with `http` and `https`. Screen is added to the question,

Comment: This error happens on the client and typically means that the correlation cookie is not set - or for some reasons has not been sent.

You need to check your network traces if you can find a reason why the cookie got "lost".

Answer (score -1):

This can happen for multiple reasons:

1. When the redirect URL defined in the application callback path does not match with any of the redirect URLs defined in the identity server (application registration in Azure AD in this case). Verify that. Also note [Redirect URI (reply URL) restrictions and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url).
2. <strike>Default cookie policy is overriding OpenIdConnect cookie setting. In that case remove</strike>, UPDATE: Relax cookie policy to allow non-secure. Update `app.UseCookiePolicy()` in `Configure` method in Startup.cs like below.

```cs
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions {
 Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.None, // if in debug mode
 MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified
});
```

3. [Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction) is not correctly configured across your nodes. Though it's not required for local debugging, but just a note for deployed environment since I don't see that in your startup code.

> I really need to make it work over http, because some of our developers can't use https for local debug.

For local debugging it's fine. But ensure you use https for deployed environment.

On a side note (not related to this problem), the authentication and authorization code integration with Microsoft identity platform can be simplified using [Microsoft Identity Web authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-identity-web).

Comment: Redirect URL mathes, otherwise it wouldn't work with HTTP, and it produces different error in this case on Azure side. Removing `app.UseCookiePolicy()` doesn't help. Data protection is not used.  Microsoft Identity Web authentication library can't be used here, because it doesn't support external login provider scenario https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/133

Comment: Your question has tag 'azure-active-directory' and also you said "I'm trying to implement user authentication with AzureAd" in the start. You should probably update the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: The question includes code with obvious use of external provider and `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync`. Don't see what should be updated in the question

Comment: Updated `app.UseCookiePolicy` (point #2) in my answer. Please check.

Comment: It doesn't help, sorry